# Oracle SQL for Distinct Values in Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have 10 columns with names for different task numbers. I want a list of all of the names distinctly.

I have  tried this and am getting Oracle Error.

```
select distinct(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10) from x where y is not null;
```

a1 - a10 are all names and I just want the aggregated list of distinct values.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`. And in Oracle writing `(column_1, column_2)` is an error, that's why your query doesn't work.

Comment: my query doesn't work without the parenthesis either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a lateral join:

```
select distinct a
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.a1 as a from dual union all
      select t.a2 from dual union all
      select t.a3 from dual union all
      select t.a4 from dual union all
      select t.a5 from dual union all
      select t.a6 from dual union all
      select t.a7 from dual union all
      select t.a8 from dual union all
      select t.a9 from dual union all
      select t.a10 from dual
     ) s
where a is not null;
```

In earlier versions, you can use `union all`:

```
select a1 from t where a1 is not null
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select a2 from t where a2 is not null
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT distinct A 
FROM X
UNPIVOT(
    A  -- unpivot_clause
    FOR A_N --  unpivot_for_clause
    IN ( -- unpivot_in_clause
        a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10
    )
);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.